# Question regarding port forwarding from local to remote

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding

Hi am just learning some port forwarding concepts and my doubt/question is below.
I have a remote ec2 where jasper (j.s.p.r) is running on 7000 port, i can only access this jasper ec2 instance via a bastion server b.s.t.n then ssh to j.s.p.r .
Now my question is i need to be able to deploy the jasper reports from local jasper studio directly on to the j.s.p.r server by forwarding my port.
So here is what i am using to achieve the same but not successfully.

```
ssh -N -L 7000:j.s.p.r:7000 -p 22 xxid@b.s.t.n
```

Comment: does bstn server provide ssh access? Assuming that it does and you can connect to it without issues, when you try to connect to local port 7000 once the port is up what error message is shown (in the client app you are using to connect to port 7000 and in the ssh client)? Another interesting thing to see would be to show `netstat -lntp` once ssh session is up.

Comment: yes bstn server provide ssh access, how can i make sure that my local port 7000 is connected to remote port 7000 of j.s.p.r ?

Comment: Well, once you start ssh and the session is established, `netstat -lntp` should should you that the port is listening. Then, you can give it a try with telnet (`telnet localhost 7000`). If there is a problem, there should be some error output on the ssh client.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.